# Factory-boy property attributes?

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, factory-boy

I have a recipe like this:

```
import factory
from models import Foobar


class MenuItemFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem

    name = 'Default Foobar'
    url = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: '/%s' % o.name)
```

I want to add dynamic properties, like `slug`, but I want to do it in a separate method. I want this, since writing any more complex logic in lambda one-liners would be, well, ugly.

One thought came to mind, using a `property` method, like they do in Django models. For example:

```
class MenuItemFactory(factory.Factory):
    ...

    @property
    def url(self):
        return '/%s' % self.name
```

Is there a way, similar to this, that will accomplish what I'm trying to do?

*EDIT*

What I want to accomplish in the end is this:

```
menu_item = MenuItemFactory(name='foobar')

menu_item.name = 'foobar'
menu_item.url = '/foobar'
```

Where `slug` acts as a dynamic attribute. In other words, I'm looking for a proper place to store my *dynamic attribute logic*.

Comment: do you want to give a function to LazyAttribute at class creation ? or set a property on the fly after class creation ?

Comment: @bboumend I want to set a property on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its pretty simple, took me a while to find it in the docs.

```
@factory.lazy_attribute
def url(self):
    return '/%s' % self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the property builtin https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property

```
class Test:
    name = 'bar'

def fget(self):
    return self.name

def fset(self, name):
    self.name = name

Test.slug = property(fget=fget, fset=fset)
t = Test()
print(t.slug)    # 'bar'
t.slug = 'foo'
print(t.slug)    # 'foo'
```